# SQL Select row from a table which has a link with every possible value that exists in a column in another Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have something like this two tables:

```
  A
 ____
| ID |   
|----|
| 1  |
| 2  |
 ----

  B
 ____ ______
| ID | TYPE |      
|----|------|   
| 1  |  Q   |   
| 2  |  W   |
| 1  |  W   |   
 ---- ------
```

Here i want to return 1 from table A cause it's linked with all possible types that exist in table B.

EDIT:
I don't know before the query what all possible types are

Comment: do you know in advance how many distinct types exist in the table? Or is it something that needs to be determined dynamically?

Comment: @sstan I don't know, it's something that needs to be determined dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always try this:

```
select id
  from b
 group by id
having count(distinct type) = (select count(distinct type) from b)
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much!! :)